# Cordova Deployment Error

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad

so I'm making a Phonegap/Cordova app. Everything is working fine on the Android part of the project, the only part giving me a bit of a headache is the iOS side of the project. So whenever I run `cordova run ios` it opens and deploys the app on my simulator, which is exactly what I want, but whenever I connect my iPad and run `cordova run ios --device` it gives me an error:

```
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Phonegap Projects/MyProject/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,La Cava Express.xcworkspace,-scheme,La Cava Express,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,La Cava Express.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Phonegap Projects/MyProject/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Phonegap Projects/MyProject/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can go about fixing this and get it running on my iPad? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did u try using xcode ?

Comment: Yeah, it also gives me an error when I try to run it. It says something about a provisioning profile. So I tried to log in to Apple Developers but I have no idea where to create one. This is the very first time I've ever tried to build an iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to open your project in Xcode from `platforms/ios/projectname.xcodeproj`

And then select the specific device and run the application.

And for that you have to create the provisioning certificate from apple developer.
This is the official [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html) from the iOS, how to create certificates.
And the other [link](http://lessons.livecode.com/m/4069/l/32957-how-do-i-create-a-distribution-profile-for-ios) is also helpful (very helpful).

Please refer this. This is very helpful and will do your work.